# How to create scroll animated effect in adobe premiere pro or after effect?

Tags: after-effects, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I want to create a scroll effect for guitar chords change like this video from youtube video
https://youtu.be/aNHpF6GvNl0

Can I achieved this using adobe premiere pro? What can I do to achieved this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

it will be difficult, but possible. and to do this, you will have to deal with the expressions in after effect.
there you create the entire project, with all the necessary settings and export it as MOGRT. then it will only be necessary to add it to the premier and replace the default images with the necessary ones.